# how to dynamically assign id to controls - controls are inside datalist in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datalist, itemdatabound

I am using datalist for showing datas. Datas are test questions with 4 options.I have 50 questions displaying in datalist.

By using ItemDataBound event - i am making visible only one question with 4 options to user. Remaining questions are invisible . In the Itemdatabound event - i am assigning id to the radio buttons. but also id is not assigned to the datalist ,it showing different id.

```
  <div class="widget">
                <div class="widget-header" align="center" style="background: #4a98c9; color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <h4>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Question : "></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionNo" runat="server" Text="0 of 0"></asp:Label></h4>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HdCurrentQuestSlNo" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HdfMinTime" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HdfSecTime" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HdfQSlNo" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HdQuestCount" runat="server" Value="0"/>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-content">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="PanelQuestBlock" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Width="100%" Height="325px">
                                <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="DataListQuestion" 
                                    onitemdatabound="DataListQuestion_ItemDataBound" 
                                    onitemcreated="DataListQuestion_ItemCreated">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="questdisplayId" id="divQuestBlock" runat="server">
                                            <div>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID='HdSlNo' runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("SlNo") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdUserQuestId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("UserQuestionId") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdTotalOptions" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("TotalOptions") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdQuestAnsweredTimeSecs" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("AnsweredTimeSecs") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdOptionAnswered" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("OptionAnswered") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Question" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="answer-row" id="divOption1" runat="server">
                                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option1" runat="server" GroupName="Answer" value="1" Text='<%# Eval("Option1") %>'
                                                    CssClass="rdbtn" Style="vertical-align: middle" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblOpt1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="answer-row" id="divOption2" runat="server">
                                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option2" runat="server" GroupName="Answer" value="2" Text='<%# Eval("Option2") %>'
                                                    CssClass="rdbtn" Style="vertical-align: middle" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblOpt2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="answer-row" id="divOption3" runat="server">
                                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option3" runat="server" GroupName="Answer" value="3" Text='<%# Eval("Option3") %>'
                                                    CssClass="rdbtn" Style="vertical-align: top; left: auto;" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblOpt3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="answer-row" id="divOption4" runat="server">
                                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option4" runat="server" GroupName="Answer" value="4" Text='<%# Eval("Option4") %>'
                                                    CssClass="rdbtn" Style="vertical-align: text-top" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblOpt4" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </div>  
                                            <div class="answer-row" id="divOption5" runat="server">
                                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Option5" runat="server" GroupName="Answer" value="4" Text='<%# Eval("Option5") %>'
                                                    CssClass="rdbtn" Style="vertical-align: text-top" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblOpt5" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </div>                                               
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:DataList>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="span8" align="center">                                                
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear Selection" 
                                                CssClass="btn btn-warning" OnClientClick="Clearbutton();" 
                                                />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save & Next" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClientClick="Savebutton()"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="span4" align="center">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnReview" runat="server" Text="Mark Review & Next" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClientClick="Reviewbutton()"/>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" Text="Finish" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClientClick="Finishbutton()"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnReview" />
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnClear" />
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DataListQuestion" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>

if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {                
HiddenField HdSlNo = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HdSlNo");
                RadioButton Option1 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("Option1");
                RadioButton Option2 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("Option2");
                RadioButton Option3 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("Option3");
                RadioButton Option4 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("Option4");
                RadioButton Option5 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("Option5");

                Option1.ID = "rdbtnoption1_" + HdSlNo.Value.ToString();
                Option2.ID = "rdbtnoption2_" + HdSlNo.Value.ToString();
                Option3.ID = "rdbtnoption3_" + HdSlNo.Value.ToString();
                Option4.ID = "rdbtnoption4_" + HdSlNo.Value.ToString();
                Option5.ID = "rdbtnoption5_" + HdSlNo.Value.ToString();
}
```

In my design page code , using Datalist i am binding 50 questions . while binding itself i am hiding 2 to 50 questions . Question 1 only visible. I tried to give dynamic id for every questions and options using event databound and rowcreated. First it got error , after that i changed properties as ClientIDMode="Static"  for controls.it shown different id. But if i click any button event again it clear the id's.again it shows old ids only.

Comment: I don't believe you need to assign IDs in code. Rather, if you assign IDs in the template, the list will then auto assign composite IDs. Could you show yout list template?

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code !

Comment: If I understand you correct, you cannot do what you want (at least, relatively easy), because of what @WiktorZychla mentions - the list will auto assign composite ID's to make sure each IDs is unique. Again - if I understand you correctly, you'd need to overwrite the datalist functionality to do it. You should properly rethink your approach. What are you trying to accomplish with the dynamical id that makes you want to define it like this?